# I’ve committed a lot of sins. Will Allah for give me?

Tags: homosexuality

Please don’t judge me
I’m a girl and I’ve been attracted to girls since I was a little girl. I never thought abou the possiblity of me being gay because I lived  in a Muslim country.  I never even thought about it. I thought ever girl felt  the same way I feel about women’s body.  Last year I met this girl and I fell in love with her. This is first the first time I ever fell in love with anybody. Everything start to make sense. I hateted myself so much for that. I told myself your going to hell for being attracted women anyways so stopped praying. Or doing any good deeds. I started watching lesbian porn. And now I’m addicted to it. I  love Allah so much and I want repeat to Allah, but I don’t know if Allah will forgive me. My question is what can I do to become better Muslim and will Allah forgive me?

Answer (score 1):

https://youtu.be/UuID-GS--k0

Watch the link in above. 
Ask forgiveness from allah and turn back to allah. 
He is most merciful inshallah will forgive you. 
Yes homosexuality is prohibited in islam it not genetic you should not blame your parents for this and prohibite watching porn as adultery is also the major sin just like homosexuality.